# spotify api axios react post request 403 error

Tags: reactjs, axios, spotify

```
makePlaylist = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        let playlist = {name: this.state.text, public:false}
        axios.post(
            `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${this.state.user_id}/playlists`, playlist,
          {headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token
          }
        }
        )
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

and I get the following error

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/my_user_id_here/playlists 403 error
```

I looked up the documentation online at

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/create-playlist/

and it looks like I'm setting things up as far as I can tell. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong with the request? I know the access token is valid.

Comment: Can you try specifying the 'Content-Type' header to 'application/json'

Comment: Aww tried that. Added line "Content-Type": "application/json" below authorization and got same 403 error.

Comment: Have you added the playlist-modify-private scope to your authorize request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Trying to create a playlist when you do not have the user’s authorization returns error 403 Forbidden." Make sure that the Spotify app that you made in Dashboard has the proper scope permissions on the user you are trying to create the playlist for.
 Here is the scope for creating a private playlist: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/scopes/#playlist-modify-private


Here is the tutorial for setting up authorization with passing in a scope:
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/